# How to make a HTTP REQUEST with Cookies in Java

Tags: java, http, request

i need help with cookies and http requests, basically i'm trying to make an http request and i was wondering if it's possible to send specific cookies in the request to use as authentication method.

i tried using apache apache's httpclient but had no success

Comment: What did you try? A quick search provides plenty of examples. You could for example follow https://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-cookies.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

While Apache has cookie support the JDK does as well

```
CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());
```

You want to add custom cookies then

```
CookieManager manager=(CookieManager)CookieHandler.getDefault();
CookiesStore store=manager.getCookieStore();

HttpCookie cookie=new HttpCookie("myCookie","myValue");
cookie.setDomain("Your server domain");
cookie.setPath("/");
store.add(null,cookie);
```

You then make your regular requests using [HttpURLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)

This cookie handler will be shared by all your connections

if your using java [HttpClient](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html) your can set an cookie handler [per client](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.Builder.html#cookieHandler(java.net.CookieHandler))

[CookieHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/net/CookieHandler.html),[CookieStore](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/net/CookieStore.html),[HttpCookie](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/net/HttpCookie.html)